# Laravel nova on resource create page show custom message

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I want to show custom message on laravel nova resouse create new page.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be positioned *exactly* the same as your screenshot, but:

```
Heading::make('<p>I want to show some message after new custom listing.</p>')
    ->asHtml()
    ->onlyOnForms()
    ->hideWhenUpdating()
```

... as the first form field would largely do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much its worked... actually, just I want to show some message thanks, bro.